# Excel - SUM or SUMIF all columns of a 2D array where rows are filtered by a horizontal function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I want to SUM multiple columns but only for rows whose SUM is  >0.  One approach that works is to add an extra column that in essence excludes rows whose SUM is <0 and then sum that extra column as in the screenshot below.  My desire is to eliminate the helper column and create a single formula based only on the original data that returns the same result.  I've tried to include FILTER() inside a SUMIF() and a few other possibilities but to no avail.

Note: I am on O365 with dynamic array support if that helps.  Thanks in advance.

[image: Desired output in cell G2, but without the need of formula in column E]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you mean, using the [MMult](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mmult-function-40593ed7-a3cd-4b6b-b9a3-e4ad3c7245eb) function will help convert the matrix `A2:C4` to `E2:E4` as you say.

-You can use the [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function, if you have Office365-Insider,

```
=LET(x,A2:C4,y,MMULT(x*1,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(x))^0),SUM(y*(y>0)))
```

-Or missing LET:

```
=SUM(MMULT(A2:C4*1,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A2:C4))^0)*(MMULT(A2:C4*1,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A2:C4))^0)>0))
```

The reason I use **x*1** is to avoid possible errors if you leave a cell blank.

Comment: Wow!  I don't have Insider, but based on what I just read about LET(), I have a ton of use for it.

Comment: @dfunky1 you can tried LET with Excel Online, it looks like it's available except for the lambda function!

Comment: Thank you!  I took me a little bit to digest that, but I think I got it.  I did make a minor modification though to make it reusable with new data;  basically reference the columns instead of the array.  `=SUM(MMULT(A:C*1,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A:C))^0)*MMULT(A:C*1,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A:C))^0)>0))`

Answer (score 1):

In `G2`, enter formula :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MMULT(A2:C4,{1;1;1})>0)*MMULT(A2:C4,{1;1;1}))
```

[image]